# GTK app has huge memory footprint, can't find any leaks

Tags: c, memory-leaks, gstreamer, gtk3, glib

I have a simple GTK-app. I created the design with glade (it is linked as RO-data into the binary) and load it with `gtk_builder_new_from_string`. In another c-file all the callback-functions are implemented.

**Loading the glade xml-file:**

```
builder = gtk_builder_new_from_string(GUI_CRAZYCART_GLADE_FILE, (gssize) GUI_CRAZYCART_GLADE_SIZE);

widgets->window = GTK_WINDOW(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "CrazyCart"));
assert(widgets->window != NULL);

widgets->win_print = GTK_WINDOW(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "win_print"));
assert(widgets->win_print != NULL);

... // more of the lines above, all the widgets I need   

gtk_builder_connect_signals(builder, widgets);
g_object_unref(builder);

gtk_widget_show_all(GTK_WIDGET(widgets->window));
gtk_widget_hide(widgets->wdgt_email_pw);

gtk_window_maximize(widgets->window);
gtk_window_fullscreen(widgets->window);

// MAIN LOOP - APP WAITS HERE UNTIL EXIT
gtk_main();
// MAIN LOOP - APP WAITS HERE UNTIL EXIT
```

Similarly with the CSS-files, etc.

However, when I press just random buttons and watch the application with *htop* I can see the used memory (*RES*) rise up very quickly. The buttons essentially don't do anything.

I would like to run it on a raspberry pi3, but after some time executing it (it is controlling a racing game on karts) it crashes, because no memory is left.

I checked already with valgrind, but it outputs a logfile several MB large, it makes it very difficult to comb through it (using online available supp-files didn't help much) and I could only find "leaks" which are one time inits by external libraries, like gstreamer, libfontconfig, gtk, etc. Also, gcc's sanitizer outputs not much of significance (mostly libfontconfig because I am using the toy-functions).

It is approaching 1GB RES-memory after 30min of usage. It slowing down after that a little, however still rising. Also, repeatedly focusing and unfocusing the window rises the memory usage.

**Sample-callback:**

```
void VISIBILITY_DEFAULT on_kart_color_editing (
            GtkTreeView         *tree_view,
            GtkTreePath         *path,
            GtkTreeViewColumn   *column,
            App_Widgets         *widgets)
{
    const char *title = gtk_tree_view_column_get_title(column);
    if (hash(title) != hash(_("Colour"))) return;

    GtkTreeIter iter;
    GdkRGBA color;
    guint cart_id;
    guint id;
    char *name;

    gui_show_color_dialog(widgets->window, &color);

    gtk_tree_model_get_iter(GTK_TREE_MODEL(widgets->tv_car_store), &iter, path);
    gtk_list_store_set(widgets->tv_car_store, &iter, COL_CAR_COLOR, &color, -1);
    gtk_tree_model_get(GTK_TREE_MODEL(widgets->tv_car_store), &iter, COL_CAR_DRIVER, &name, COL_KARTNUM, &cart_id, COL_CAR_ID, &id, -1);

    gtk_tree_selection_unselect_all(gtk_tree_view_get_selection(tree_view));

    game_change_player((uint8_t) id, (uint8_t) (cart_id - 1U), gdkrgba_to_argb(&color), name);

    g_free(name);
}
```

I have also tried finding glib objects with reference-counter > 0 using [this post](http://blog.asleson.org/2016/11/09/debugging-gobject-reference-count-problems/) however again most leaks were due to objects from external libs (and a huge file).

**It seems as gstreamer/my sound playing code is one of the reasons for the increasing memory usage**

**sound.c, for gstreamer:**

```
struct snd_data_t
{
    GstElement *pipeline, *pitch;
    GstElement *source;

    guint bus_watch_id;

    void (*cb_start)(void *);
    void (*cb_end)(void *);

    void *data_start;
    void *data_end;
};

// return const, because user mustn't free or alter it!
const void *snd_play_mem(const char *buf, size_t len, void (*cb_start)(void *), void *data_start, void (*cb_end)(void *), void *data_end)
{
    GstElement *source;
    GstBuffer *gst_buffer;
    char *buf_cloned;
    struct snd_data_t *snd_data;
    GstCaps *caps_ogg;

    snd_data = emalloc(sizeof *snd_data);
    source = gst_element_factory_make("appsrc", "mem-source");

    caps_ogg = gst_caps_new_empty_simple("audio/ogg");
    gst_app_src_set_caps((GstAppSrc*) source, caps_ogg);
    gst_app_src_set_size((GstAppSrc*) source,  (gint64) len);
    gst_app_src_set_stream_type((GstAppSrc*) source, GST_APP_STREAM_TYPE_STREAM);
    gst_app_src_set_max_bytes((GstAppSrc*) source, len);
    gst_caps_unref(caps_ogg);

    buf_cloned = g_memdup(buf, (guint) len);
    gst_buffer = gst_buffer_new_wrapped(buf_cloned, len);

    gst_app_src_push_buffer((GstAppSrc*) source, gst_buffer);
    gst_app_src_end_of_stream((GstAppSrc*) source);

    snd_data->source = source;
    snd_data->cb_start = cb_start;
    snd_data->cb_end = cb_end;
    snd_data->data_start = data_start;
    snd_data->data_end = data_end;

    snd_thread_play(snd_data);

    return snd_data;
}

// return const, because user mustn't free or alter it!
const void *snd_play_file(const char *path, void (*cb)(void *), void *data)
{
    GstElement *source;
    struct snd_data_t *snd_data;

    snd_data = emalloc(sizeof *snd_data);
    source = gst_element_factory_make("filesrc", "file-source");

    g_object_set(G_OBJECT(source), "location", path, NULL);

    snd_data->source = source;
    snd_data->cb_end = cb;
    snd_data->data_end = data;
    snd_data->cb_start = NULL;
    snd_data->data_start = NULL;

    snd_thread_play(snd_data);

    return snd_data;
}

void snd_stop(const void *data)
{
    if (data == NULL) return;

    // ugly hack, because const (user mustn't free or alter it)!
    struct snd_data_t *snd_data = (struct snd_data_t *)(intptr_t) data;

    gst_element_set_state(snd_data->pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);

    gst_object_unref(GST_OBJECT(snd_data->pipeline));
    g_source_remove(snd_data->bus_watch_id);

    free(snd_data);
}

void snd_set_speed(const void *data, double speed)
{
    if (data == NULL) return;

    // ugly hack, because const (user mustn't free or alter it)!
    struct snd_data_t *snd_data = (struct snd_data_t *)(intptr_t) data;

    g_object_set(snd_data->pitch, "pitch", speed, "tempo", speed, NULL);
}

static void *snd_thread_play(void *data)
{
    GstElement *source, *decoder, *conv, *pitch, *sink;
    GstBus *bus;
    struct snd_data_t *snd_data;

    snd_data = data;
    snd_data->pipeline = gst_pipeline_new("CrazyCart");

    source    = snd_data->source;
    decoder = gst_element_factory_make("decodebin",        "decoder");
    conv    = gst_element_factory_make("audioconvert",    "converter");
    pitch    = gst_element_factory_make("pitch",            "pitcher");
    sink    = gst_element_factory_make("autoaudiosink",    "audio-output");

    if (!snd_data->pipeline || !source || !decoder || !conv || !sink || !pitch) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", _("'gst_element_factory_make' failed"));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    snd_data->pitch = pitch;

    bus = gst_pipeline_get_bus(GST_PIPELINE(snd_data->pipeline));
    snd_data->bus_watch_id = gst_bus_add_watch(bus, snd_bus_call, snd_data);
    gst_object_unref(bus);

    gst_bin_add_many(GST_BIN(snd_data->pipeline), source, decoder, conv, pitch, sink, NULL);

    gst_element_link_many(source, decoder, NULL);    
    gst_element_link_many(conv, pitch, sink, NULL);
    g_signal_connect(decoder, "pad-added", G_CALLBACK(snd_on_pad_added), conv);

    gst_element_set_state(snd_data->pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);

    #ifdef DEBUG
    GST_DEBUG_BIN_TO_DOT_FILE_WITH_TS(GST_BIN(snd_data->pipeline), GST_DEBUG_GRAPH_SHOW_ALL, "crazycart");
    #endif

    return NULL;
}

static void snd_on_pad_added(
    __attribute__ ((unused))    GstElement *element, 
                                GstPad *pad, 
                                gpointer data
)
{
    GstPad *sinkpad;
    GstElement *conv = (GstElement *) data;

    sinkpad = gst_element_get_static_pad(conv, "sink");

    gst_pad_link(pad, sinkpad);
    gst_object_unref(sinkpad);
}

static gboolean snd_bus_call(
    UNUSED    GstBus *bus, 
            GstMessage *msg, 
            gpointer data
)
{
    struct snd_data_t *snd_data = data;

    switch (GST_MESSAGE_TYPE(msg)) 
    {
        case GST_MESSAGE_EOS:
            gst_element_set_state(snd_data->pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);

            gst_object_unref(GST_OBJECT(snd_data->pipeline));
            g_source_remove(snd_data->bus_watch_id);

            void (*cb_end)(void *) = snd_data->cb_end;
            void *cb_data = snd_data->data_end;

            free(snd_data);

            if (cb_end != NULL)
                cb_end(cb_data);

            return false;
            break;

        case GST_MESSAGE_ERROR: 
        {
            gchar  *debug;
            GError *error;

            gst_message_parse_error(msg, &error, &debug);
            g_free(debug);

            g_printerr("Error: %s\n", error->message);
            g_error_free(error);

            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        } break;

        case GST_MESSAGE_STREAM_START:
            if (snd_data->cb_start != NULL)
                snd_data->cb_start(snd_data->data_start);
            break;

        default:
            //DPRINT_VERB("GST_MESSAGE_TYPE %d\n", GST_MESSAGE_TYPE(msg));
            break;
    }

    return true;
}
```

---

I have created a simple test app to test my gstreamer code, to be able to debug it seperately. Also, I followed [this presentation](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/events/gstreamer-conference/2016/Guillaume%20Desmottes%20-%20Tracking%20Memory%20Leaks.pdf#page=13), to get a few tipps how to find leaks. So this post doesn't get too long, I uploaded my [log files to github](https://github.com/Freddy1404/so_memleaks).

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wcast-qual"
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wcast-align"
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wconversion"
#include <gst/gst.h>
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
#include <glib.h>

#include "utils.h"
#include "sound.h"
#include "debug.h"

static char **argv_s;

void next_song(GMainLoop *loop)
{
    snd_play_file(argv_s[2], (void (*)(void *)) &g_main_loop_quit, loop);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    argv_s = argv;

    GMainLoop *loop = g_main_loop_new(NULL, FALSE);
    gst_init(&argc, &argv);

    char *mime;
    get_mime_type(&mime, argv[1]);
    printf("Mime [%s]: %s\n", argv[1], mime);
    free(mime);

    const void *p = snd_play_file(argv[1], (void (*)(void *)) &next_song, loop);

    DPRINT_VERB("sleeping 10!\n");
    sleep(10);

    snd_set_speed(p, 1.5);

    g_main_loop_run(loop);

    DPRINT_VERB("deinit!\n");
    gst_deinit();
    g_main_loop_unref(loop);

    return 0;
}
```

---

What am I missing here? Why is my (in my opinion) rather small and simple app using so much memory and how can I reduce it?

Comment: Which version of Gtk are you using? This sounds like a leak related to gstreamer. Are you using appsrc or appsink elements in your pipeline?

Comment: @lb90 I use GTK 3.24.5. Yes, I use appsrc to play ogg files from memory. I edited my question and posted the whole code how I control gstreamer.

Comment: Can you confirm stopping gstreamer playback doesn't make the leak go away?

Comment: When you pass a buffer to the appsrc element with gst_app_src_push_buffer() the appsrc takes a reference and you have to drop your reference (that's because GstBuffer does not have support for a floating reference). Add a call to gst_buffer_unref(gst_buffer) at the end of snd_play_mem().

Comment: @TingPing Yes, there seem to be some minor problems somewhere else, but the memory is rising (and stagnating at some point) much slower, if I don't play background music (`snd_play_file` returns immediately)

Comment: @lb90 That will unfortunately force close the application and print `ERROR:gstappsrc.c:1225:gst_app_src_create: assertion failed (GST_IS_BUFFER_LIST (obj))`

Comment: Right. I didn't know that, but gst_app_src_push_buffer() takes ownership of the buffer, so your code is ok. Are you sure that you correctly release the buffer passed as argument to snd_play_mem?

Comment: @lb90 Yes, it is an ogg-file which is statically linked into the binary, so no need to free it.

Comment: Your initial guess, @lb90, seems to be correct. Memory is leaking somewhere, having to do with GstBuffer and GstMemory (https://github.com/Freddy1404/so_memleaks/blob/master/tst_snd_gtrace.log)

Comment: How do you "statically link" an OGG file into a program?

Comment: I think a better approach than function-pointer casting would be to have `next_song` take a `void *` instead. Then the pointer will implicitly convert. Also, you're inconsistently using `UNUSED` and `__attribute__((unused))`.

Comment: @S.S.Anne By creating an object file with `ld -r -b binary` and linking that into the `rodata`-section of my binary. This is done to condense everything into one file to be able to share it easily.

Yes, I just recently changed to the macro `UNUSED` due to its shortness and some parts of the code are still to be done.

Comment: I think `UNUSED` could also be used for portability since `__attribute__` is a GNU extension.

Comment: Hey, you wrote:
> Also, gcc's sanitizer outputs not much of significance (mostly libfontconfig because I am using the toy-functions).

Did you mean `mtrace`?

I would definitely give a go with [ASan/LSan](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizer#using-addresssanitizer) with which you can find the leak(s) faster!

Comment: @lnksz No, I meant ASan.